# Is it possible that a container instance isn't really a container?

Tags: amazon-ecs

I read the [AmazonECS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/Welcome.html) documentation and also [this](https://medium.com/boltops/gentle-introduction-to-how-aws-ecs-works-with-example-tutorial-cea3d27ce63d) article which gave a basic explanation on each term, including:

> Container Instance — This is just an EC2 instance that is part of an ECS Cluster and has docker and the ecs-agent running on it.

I feel a bit confused. I thought every `task` is a `container` which runs on the `EC2 instance` that is part of the `ECS` cluster. So how come the `EC2 instance` gets to be called like that? Or is the `EC2 instance` also a `container` and I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you think *container instance*, think:

> An EC2 instance configured to run containers (ECS tasks) by having the ECS agent and being part of an ECS cluster.

Essentially, ECS keeps track of the EC2 instances that have been associated with the cluster, including metadata about them. That means that in addition to being tracked as EC2 instances, they're also tracked as "Container Instances". If you have the AWS CLI installed, take a look at `aws ecs describe-container-instances` to see some of the metadata about container instances.

```
$ aws ecs describe-container-instances --container-instance <container instance>
{
    "failures": [],
    "containerInstances": [
        {
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "registeredAt": 1442818969.168,
            "registeredResources": [
                {
                    "integerValue": 2048,
                    "longValue": 0,
                    "type": "INTEGER",
                    "name": "CPU",
                    "doubleValue": 0.0
                },
                {
                    "integerValue": 1957,
                    "longValue": 0,
                    "type": "INTEGER",
                    "name": "MEMORY",
                    "doubleValue": 0.0
                },
                {
                    "name": "PORTS",
                    "longValue": 0,
                    "doubleValue": 0.0,
                    "stringSetValue": [
                        "22",
                        "2376",
                        "2375",
                        "51678",
                        "51679"
                    ],
                    "type": "STRINGSET",
                    "integerValue": 0
                },
                {
                    "name": "PORTS_UDP",
                    "longValue": 0,
                    "doubleValue": 0.0,
                    "stringSetValue": [],
                    "type": "STRINGSET",
                    "integerValue": 0
                }
            ],
            "ec2InstanceId": "i-98135490825890725",
            "agentConnected": true,
            "containerInstanceArn": "arn:aws:ecs:ca-central-1:23490141:container-instance/123984129047912347012340",
            "pendingTasksCount": 0,
            "remainingResources": [
                {
                    "integerValue": 1923,
                    "longValue": 0,
                    "type": "INTEGER",
                    "name": "CPU",
                    "doubleValue": 0.0
                },
                {
                    "integerValue": 1925,
                    "longValue": 0,
                    "type": "INTEGER",
                    "name": "MEMORY",
                    "doubleValue": 0.0
                },
                {
                    "name": "PORTS",
                    "longValue": 0,
                    "doubleValue": 0.0,
                    "stringSetValue": [
                        "22",
                        "2376",
                        "2375",
                        "51678",
                        "51679"
                    ],
                    "type": "STRINGSET",
                    "integerValue": 0
                },
                {
                    "name": "PORTS_UDP",
                    "longValue": 0,
                    "doubleValue": 0.0,
                    "stringSetValue": [],
                    "type": "STRINGSET",
                    "integerValue": 0
                }
            ],
            "version": 3197,
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.syslog"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ecs.ami-id",
                    "value": "ami-0f552e0a86f08b660"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.none"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.json-file"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ecs.vpc-id",
                    "value": "vpc-2309423409"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.17"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ecs.capability.docker-plugin.local"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ecs.capability.task-cpu-mem-limit"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.30"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.31"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.32"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ecs.capability.container-health-check"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ecs.subnet-id",
                    "value": "subnet-13412345"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ecs.availability-zone",
                    "value": "us-east-1c"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ecs.instance-type",
                    "value": "t3.small"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role-network-host"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.24"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.25"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.26"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.27"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.privileged-container"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.28"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ecs.cpu-architecture",
                    "value": "x86_64"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ecs.capability.cni-plugin-version",
                    "value": "93f43776-2018.10.0"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ecs.capability.secrets.ssm.environment-variables"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ecs.capability.pid-ipc-namespace-sharing"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.20"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ecs.os-type",
                    "value": "linux"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.21"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.22"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.23"
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ecs.capability.private-registry-authentication.secretsmanager"
                }
            ],
            "versionInfo": {
                "agentVersion": "1.22.0",
                "agentHash": "26518174",
                "dockerVersion": "DockerVersion: 18.06.1-ce"
            },
            "runningTasksCount": 1,
            "attachments": []
        }
    ]
}
```

But, no, ECS container instances aren't AFAIK, containers themselves. They're virtual servers configured to run containers using ECS.